# Can an array be the value for an influxdb entry?

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I am trying to write an influxdb query such that a measurement looks like

`dummydata value=1,2,3,4`

and influxdb doesn't like this format.  I'm guessing influxdb cannot do this, but I can't find any documentation that says it cannot, nor do I see a feasible workaround.  I have to write 500 points per timestamp: it seems to me that 500 separate measurements per timestamp would get hairy quick.

So:

1. Can influxdb accept an array/list as a value
2. If not, is there a workaround
3. Or is influxdb just the wrong tool for this job?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

InfluxDB [accepts](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/write_protocols/write_syntax/#data-types) strings, float64s, int64s, and booleans as field values.

> it seems to me that 500 separate measurements per timestamp would get hairy quick.

That's where you are mistaken. InfluxDB 0.10+ is specifically designed to encourage multiple fields per point, where a field is a measured value. What you want to write is a point like this:

`dummydata value=1,value2=2,value3=3,value4=4...`

Comment: (3 years later) That seems super verbose. It adds significant "dead bytes" to the send package. I guess one could write a wrapper to turn a simple array into this sort of string, but I just assumed use mongodb 3 years ago and that's been that.